# Get top N from sorted group with SQL

Tags: mysql, database

Say I have table in this format:

[image]

I want to get top 2 from each channel but the channel order is **sorted by sum of volume first**. Expected result is:

[image]

Sum of channel B volume is 5150 which is larger than the sum of channel A with 3500.

I saw some questions that user ROW_NUMBER() but it only work to get top N from each category with no order in category. How do I approach this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ROW_NUMBER() with SUM analytical functions in ORDER BY clause -

```
SELECT channel, category, volume
  FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY channel ORDER BY volume DESC) RN,
               SUM(volume) OVER(PARTITION BY channel) tot_volume
               channel, category, volume
          FROM (SELECT channel, category, SUM(volume) volume
                  FROM your_table
                 GROUP BY channel, category
               ) t
        ) tmp
 WHERE RN <= 2
 ORDER BY tot_volume DESC, volume DESC;
```

Comment: Hi @ankit-bajpai, thanks for the answer. I missed some details before and updated the question. Turns out I need to sum the volume by category too. I try to sum it in the outer query but it doesn't give desired output. Could you take a loo one more time? Thank you!

Comment: @Muti, Can you try the updated query.

Comment: It works! So the sum is in inner query not in the other one.. Thank you for the answer, I've accepted your answer and upvoted it.

Comment: @Muti, Your'e always welcome.